# How to compile and run both at the same time for a c++ code in linux terminal?

Tags: c++, linux, g++

I am using Ubuntu(latest). If I have a `test.cpp` file in my home directory, I write two commands in terminal to compile and run this file.

```
prateek332@pp-pc:~$ g++ test.cpp 
prateek332@pp-pc:~$ ./a.out
```

Is there a way to write these two command simultaneously (or maybe even a better way). I used pipelining but it doesn't work.

```
prateek332@pp-pc:~$ g++ test.cpp | ./a.out
```

This doesn't work. It doesn't compile to new changes in `test.cpp` file, instead just runs the old code in file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`g++ test.cpp && ./a.out`
First compile and then, if it was successfull, run the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a shell function since this is something you will do often.

In **~/.bashrc** (or whatever your shell config is like ~/.zshrc)

```
function cpp() { g++ $1 && ./a.out; }
```

Now you can just type

```
cpp test.cpp
```

You can name the function whatever you want. Open a new shell window to load the function (or run `source ~/.bashrc`).